# C#: Creating a Methodheader Parser

Tags: c#, parsing, methods, text-parsing

I would like to write a parser to tell me what part of a string is a methodheader.  What is the best way to do this in C#?

The language grammar specification [can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664812%28VS.71%29.aspx).  I don't think this is proper BNF/EBNF, so perhaps there is a way to transform it into such (like an html parser that puts it into proper BNF.)

Should I use regular expressions or a custom built parser somehow?  I am restricted in that I need to build it myself without the help of outside tools.

Comment: Regarding *I am restricted in that I need to build it myself without the help of outside tools.* ... is this homework?

Comment: Wow, 4+'s. A cynical crowd I suppose. No, it's not homework. Just don't like using other people's tools, and I know how people love to jump to using them on here when regarding parsing.

Comment: So you like to re-invent the wheel?  There is very little virtue in doing that, IMO.

Comment: The reason I asked about "without the help of outside tools" is because ... well, see my answer.

Comment: @Brian: Everybody writes their first "hello world" sometime.  Are you saying they should not because it is "reinventing the wheel?"

Comment: Hmmm, all y'all please don't take this the wrong way, but the way this comment-dialogue is going is probably not productive.

Comment: Well, you didn't say this was a learning exercise.  You said that you "don't like using other people's tools."  But @Cheeso is correct.  This will be my last comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [the NRefactory library](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/NRefactory.ashx), part of the open-source SharpDevelop tool,  to be very good at parsing C# modules into an *abstract syntax tree.*  Once you have that you can scan through very easily to find the method headers, the locations, and so on.

Though its primary use is for within SharpDevelop (A GUI tool), it is a standalone DLL, and it can be used within any .NET app.   The documentation isn't very thorough, as far as I could tell, but Reflector let me examine it and figure things out pretty easily.

some code:

```
    internal static string CreateAstSexpression(string filename)
    {
        using (var fs = File.OpenRead(filename))
        {
            using (var parser = ParserFactory.CreateParser(SupportedLanguage.CSharp,
                                                           new StreamReader(fs)))
            {
                parser.Parse();

                // RetrieveSpecials() returns an IList<ISpecial>
                // parser.Lexer.SpecialTracker.RetrieveSpecials()...
                // "specials" == comments, preprocessor directives, etc.

                // parser.CompilationUnit retrieves the root node of the result AST
                return SexpressionGenerator.Generate(parser.CompilationUnit).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

The ParserFactory class is part of NRefactory.
In my case I wanted a lisp s-expression describing the C# buffer, so I wrote an S-expression generator that walked through the "CompilationUnit".  It's just a tree of nodes, starting with namespace, then class/struct/enum. Within the class/struct node, there are method nodes (as well as field, property, etc).

---

If that finished DLL is not of interest, then maybe this is.

Before finding and embracing NRefactory, I tried to produce [a wisent grammar for c#](http://www.zshare.net/download/892195817de4ec1e/). This was for use within emacs, which has a wisent engine.

I never could get it to work properly. 
Maybe it's of use to you.

---

you said that you didn't want to use "outside tools".  Not sure of the motivation for that restriction; if it is homework, then I guess it makes sense, but for other purposes, it really would be a shame to not use the well-tested and well-understood tools that are already out there.

If you take either of the suggestions I've made here, you're building on *something* that is an outside tool.  But some of the options are a little better than others.

Comment: Thanks.  I may have to rethink my restriction.

Comment: So I ended up installing git to get the entire sharp develop repository.  Was there an easy way to get just the dll?  Also, does reflector still work for you?  Last time I tried to use it it deleted itself.